# Eliminate duplicates in a list of a list

Tags: r

I have a list containing other lists and in each of those lists I would like to eliminates duplicates according to the first column. I managed to do that just for one list of the list

```
 x<-as.data.frame(list[1])
 test <-x[!duplicated(x[,1]), ]
```

but I am having troubles to apply this to all lists of the list.

For example, I have a list of list with names "1" "2" "3" "4", each containing a list of this type

A   EL1  E2L1
B   EL2  E2L2
C   EL3  E2L3
D   EL4  E2L4
E   EL5  E2L5
F   EL6  E2L6
A   EL7  E2L7

and from every list I want to eliminate every duplicate row.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a simplified example of the list you're working with.

Comment: I'm confused. Lists don't have rows and I don't see any duplicates...

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13924479/1492421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

Let's generate some sample data:

```
list = lapply(1:3, function(x)lapply(1:2, sample, size=5, x=1:5))
```

And then use `lapply`:

```
lapply(list, function(x)as.data.frame(x)[!duplicated(as.data.frame(x)[,1]), ])
```